Custom Framework with Carthage
I have an Xcode project where i have build a framework and a demo app. I use carthage to load libs for my project using:
carthage update --use-xcframeworks --platform iOS  .
I want other users able to drag and drop my created framework to their xcode project. My framework uses other libraries, i import this libraries using carthage.
My demo app build and uses my framework.
Then when i create a new project i drag & drop my framework, build the app and tells me that "No such Module xxx" so i cannot build the project with my framework.
Any help appreciated
This is the script i use to build my framework :
set -e
# ---------------------------------------------
# Vars
# ---------------------------------------------

FRAMEWORK_NAME=“MyFramework”
DEST_DIR="Build"
PROJECT_NAME="MyFramework.xcworkspace"

# ---------------------------------------------
# Build xcframework
# ---------------------------------------------

#Remove destination directory if already exists
if [ -d "${DEST_DIR}" ]; then
    rm -rf "${DEST_DIR}"
fi

# Create destination directory
mkdir -p "${DEST_DIR}"

echo "...framework for simulator"
xcodebuild -workspace ${PROJECT_NAME} \
-scheme ${FRAMEWORK_NAME} \
-configuration Release \
-sdk iphonesimulator platform=iOS\ Simulator \
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO \
IOS_INSTALL_COMBINED=NO CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="./${DEST_DIR}/iphonesimulator" \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE="bitcode" \
GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO

echo "...framework for device"
xcodebuild -workspace ${PROJECT_NAME} \
-scheme ${FRAMEWORK_NAME} \
-configuration Release \
-sdk iphoneos platform=iOS \
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=YES \
IOS_INSTALL_COMBINED=NO CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="./${DEST_DIR}/iphoneos" \
SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode" BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE="bitcode" \
GCC_INSTRUMENT_PROGRAM_FLOW_ARCS=NO CLANG_ENABLE_CODE_COVERAGE=NO

echo "...making xcframework"
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-framework "${DEST_DIR}/iphoneos/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" \
-framework "${DEST_DIR}/iphonesimulator/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.framework" \
-output "${DEST_DIR}/${FRAMEWORK_NAME}.xcframework"


